Why would a simple input statement cause a runtime error? (Work@tech IDE) NZEC error
Since replit has started charging for collaborative IDE's i've been trying to explore good alternatives.
I am experiencing NZEC error when trying to run a simple program such as:
answer = ""
answer = input()

Why would this cause a runtime error? Or just another suggestion of a public IDE is soo welcome.
Tried in both python 2.7 and 3.5
Thank you
I've even made the program more specific:
answer = ""
answer = str(input())

Error I am getting is:
Runtime Error (NZEC)
Execution Time: 0.07 sec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py3", line 5, in 
    answer = str(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line


work@tech doesn't handle inputs very well. You can still do it by selecting "Custom input" under your code, and  type your input in the textbox which is appearing:


Thank you this is very useful, I think I may just switch IDE...
